# Saving / Restoring Eclipse state (open files, layout, ...)

Tags: eclipse

When working in Eclipse with CDT, I frequently have the need to switch contexts to work on a different issue within the same project for a while. This context switch usually requires me to have a different set of files open and sometimes also to use a different layout.

I have searched for quite some time but so far did not find a good solution (other than exiting Eclipse and copying the settings files), to simply store my current state (i.e. open files, layout, ...) and later restore it within Eclipse.

So my question is, is this context switch somehow possible in an easier way, e.g. with a plugin that I am not aware of?

Comment: As far as I know this is what workspaces are for. You can switch between them and they will remember what was where and such. 
Having said that, it would be quite straight forward to at least get all the open files, store their handles, and reopen them with a plugin.

Comment: Have you tried Mylyn? https://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/

Comment: @pandaadb: I had the impression that different workspaces would basically mean a completely new setup/environment (different path for the workspace, new checkout of all files [if they live under the workspace directory], different local history, ...). I guess this could be backup solution if I only have to switch rarely, but it definitely does not look like a light-weight solution.

Comment: @nitind: I can give Mylyn a look again. I tried it briefly quite some time ago. Back then I got the impression (but maybe this was due to the brevity of my tryout), that you would need to integrate it deeply with your tasks process and not just be a simple save workspace / restore workspace solution.

Comment: You do not need to have a different checkout. You can "import existing project" and just point both workspaces to the same projects. It is however not ideal..